# Get last inserted ID from not AUTO_INCREMENT column in MySQL

Tags: mysql

`LAST_INSERT_ID()` returns the last inserted ID from column with `AUTO_INCREMENT` property.

Firstly, is there any way to get the last inserted ID at the column which **has not** `AUTO_INCREMENT` property.

If yes, how do i get the last inserted ID?

Any ideas would be awesome.

Comment: Note that LAST_INSERT_ID is session-specific

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not always guaranteed, but you could use `MAX()`:

```
SELECT MAX(ID) FROM YourTable
```

The reason this might not be guaranteed is if you are having multiple transactions running at the same time, this could potentially select the incorrect id...

Similarly, ORDER BY with LIMIT:

```
SELECT ID FROM YourTable ORDER BY ID Desc Limit 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Does your id is Primary key?

You can check timestamp value if you have it.

In fact there are no way of getting last inserted row without autoincrement or timestamp. 
In case you can not change main table you can create other table and map autoincrement to the id you inserted.

Comment: Yes it is Primary Key. For more info please comment it on first post.